# Join jQuery elements that are already selected

Tags: jquery, dry

I know that to avoid multiple searches on a DOM tree, it is a good idea to save the selected elements, to improve performance

```
var $el = $(".el");
$el.show();
...
...
$el.show();
...
...
$el.on('click', function(){...});
```

But now I have a several items separated in variables, and I would like to do sometimes the same operation in several of them and sometimes different operations on them. I could do it like this of course:

```
var $button1 = $('.button1');
var $button2 = $('.button2');
...
...
$button1.on('click', doSomething);
$button2.on('click', doSomethingDifferent);
...
...
$button1.css(newStyles);
$button2.css(newStyles);
```

But this way, my code is not very DRY.

If I do not follow the approach of saving them into variables, my codes gets more DRY, but less efficient

```
$('.button1').on('click', doSomething);
$('.button2').on('click', doSomethingDifferent);
...
...
$('.button1, .button2').css(newStyles);
```

**Is there a way to have the best of 2 worlds?**

Here is some pseudo-code of what I had in mind..

```
var $button1 = $('.button1');
var $button2 = $('.button2');
var $buttons = $.group($button1, $button2);
...
...
$button1.on('click', doSomething);
$button2.on('click', doSomethingDifferent);
...
...
$buttons.css(newStyles);
```

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes an hour, two tops, and afterward doing so saves you that time almost immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps unsurprisingly, you use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$button1.add($button2).add($button3).doSomething();
```

Comment: Oh, well. That was easier than I thought. Thanks!